# Find content related to $(this) from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple blocks with pagination and similar classes. I am trying to use $.ajax to call and load content specific to the block. The below code gives me an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. I am very new to jquery. Any help is appreciated. P.S. changing or adding classes/IDs to pagination links is not in my control.

html

```
//block 1

    <div class="contentblock">
      <div class="ax_content">Main Content Here</div>
      <div class="frm_pagination_cont">
        <ul class="frm_pagination">
          <li><a href="?frm-page-2024=1">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="?frm-page-2024=2">2</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>

    //block 2

    <div class="contentblock">
      <div class="ax_content">Main Content Here</div>
      <div class="frm_pagination_cont">
        <ul class="frm_pagination">
          <li><a href="?frm-page-3093=1">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="?frm-page-3093=2">2</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
$('.contentblock').on('click', '.frm_pagination a', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
var link = $this.attr('href');
var pgContainer = $this.closest('.frm_pagination_cont'); //pagination container div
var contentdiv = $(pgContainer).prev('.ax_content');
$this.closest('.contentblock').append('<img class="opinions-loader-gif" src="http://dev-wp.in/wp-content/themes/headway-child/images/AjaxLoader.gif" alt=""/>');
contentdiv.animate({ opacity: 0.1 },500, function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function(html) {
            var content = $(html).$this.find('.ax_content > *'),
                pg = $(html).$this.find('.frm_pagination_cont > *');
            content.animate({ opacity: 1 },500);
            $(contentdiv).html(content);
            $(pgContainer).html(pg);
            $('.opinions-loader-gif').remove();
            $("html, body").animate({  
                scrollTop: 0 }, 350);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `$(html).$this` ? What were you trying to do here ?

Comment: change `$(html).$this.find` to `$(html).find` ?

Comment: "$(html).find" gets the content of .ax_content from block 2 as well.